# Can we use Microsoft SSMS "Network SQL server browser" in WPF application?

Tags: sql-server, wpf

On click of a button, I want to browse SQL servers available on network -Just like Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio & on selection I want to get corresponding connection string.

Is SQL network server browser dialog available in any dll? or do I need to program it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found relatively complete solution. I need to create custom dialog though,

[Working code](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/123441/sql-server-2008-backup-and-restore-databases-using)

Answer (score 1):

> Microsoft Data Connection Dialog 1.2.0
>   The data connection dialog is a
>   database tool component released with Visual Studio. It allows users
>   to build connection strings and to connect to specific data sources.
>
> In order to use the data connection dialog independently of Visual
>   Studio, we have released the standalone source code. You can integrate
>   and redistribute the source code with your application according to
>   license.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog/

Comment: Thanks for giving me direction. With keyword SMO, I am able to find relatively matching solution.